# Illegal group end indicator error in protobuf decode

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

I am getting the following error when i try to decode bytearray using protobuf.js decode

error: Illegal group end indicator for Message .SampleMessage: 1749 (not a group)
    at Error (native)
    at ProtoBuf.Reflect.MessagePrototype.decode (http://127.0.0.1:53259/libs/protobuf/dist/ProtoBuf.js:3168:31)
    at Function.Message.decode (http://127.0.0.1:53259/libs/protobuf/dist/ProtoBuf.js:2896:37)

**code snippet:**
sample.proto - file

```
message SampleMessage {
    required string text = 1;
}
```

**Java code  For encode:**

```
 SampleMessage msg = SampleProto.SampleMessage.newBuilder().setText("test data ").build();
 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
 out.writeObject(msg);
 out.flush();
```

**Decode using javascript :**

```
var ProtoBuf = dcodeIO.ProtoBuf;
var SampleMessage = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile("com/cm/model/sample.proto").build("SampleMessage");  
var msg = SampleMessage.decode(response.data);
```

Comment: That suggests your response data is incorrect. I'd be very surprised to see a group end tag in any modern protobuf message. Unfortuntaely we don't know where you got the data from... Can you post an example which includes the data itself, as a hard coded binary array?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet I have updated the input data details , which I am sending from java .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that this is the problem:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(msg);
```

Why are you using `ObjectOutputStream`? That's for Java's native binary serialization protocol, which *isn't* the same as Protocol Buffers. Even though protobuf has *some* support for Java's serialization (so that if you're already using the built-in serialization, you can still serialize protobuf messages) you shouldn't be using that unless you're using Java serialization at *both* sides.

You should be using

```
SampleMessage msg = SampleProto.SampleMessage.newBuilder().setText("test data ").build();
msg.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
```