# "Illegal group end indicator...(not a group)" when decoding gtfs-r data

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, gtfs

I'm trying to use a node.js app to regularly decode some gtfs-realtime data. It's mostly running fine, but every few hours I run into an error that crashes my app. The error message in my log says that there is an `"Illegal group end indicator for Message  .transit_realtime.FeedMessage 7 (not a group)"`

I found [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658581/illegal-group-end-indicator-error-in-protobuf-decode) on StackOverflow but it doesn't seem to solve my particular problem. Here is an outline of the code I am using to decode the gtfs-r feed:

```
//process the response
var processBuffers = function(response) {
    var data = [];
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data.push(chunk);
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        data = Buffer.concat(data);
        var decodedFeedMessage = transit.FeedMessage.decode(data);
        allData = decodedFeedMessage.entity;
        //continues processing with allData...
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs crashed issue basically happen every time, everydays that any kind of fatal error trigger. And since your received data from 3-rd party, It will very had to make sure the data always correct to prevent error as well.

The simple solution is using another system to deploy your NodeJS application. I recommend 2 tools that very popular today, **PM2** and **Passenger** . (PM2 is very simple to use). Those tool will help to auto restart your NodeJS application once it crashed

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/nodejs/ownserver/nginx/oss/install_passenger_main.html